# How Can Send to Print a Test Page to a Printer using delphi?

Tags: delphi, printing

Actually i'm working in a project which need print a test page to a particular printer. the test page must be the same which of prints Windows in the option  printer properties -> print test page.

How i can do this in delphi?

Comment: I doubt that the OS offers that as a service but no doubt someone will know how to do it!

Comment: I think you can `ShellExecute`

    `RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /k`.
    
If you run `PRINTUI` in a cmd window, you will get the documentation for the command (at least in Windows 7).

Comment: @Andreas, this can be done for a particular printer or just for the default?

Comment: @Salvador: I think it works for any printer, but I have never used the command myself. However, I think that jachguate's solution is better, and I am pretty sure that his solution works for any installed printer.

Comment: Guess I was wrong then!!

Comment: @David: The Windows API is huge; surely you know that?

Comment: @Andreas I'm a little surprised that it is exposed. I'm finding it hard to see why one would want to automate printing test pages and so why create an interface and the associated maintenance costs? But I guess there must be a real need for automating this.

Comment: @David: I have always wondered why the `ShellAbout` function is exposed to every third-party developer... But the API exposes a lot!

Comment: @David, @Andreas: I'm not surprised at all that this is exposed. Over time, fewer and fewer things in Windows are 'internal' (i.e. without public API), which is a good thing for the Windows team too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code will print the test page for the default printer:

```
uses ShellAPI, printers;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Device, Driver, Port: Array [0..255] of Char;
  hDevMode: THandle;
begin
  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, hDevmode);
  ShInvokePrinterCommand(handle, PRINTACTION_TESTPAGE, Device, nil, true );
end;
```

Result:
[image: Printer test page]

Enjoy :)

Comment: how i can use this method for a particular printer and not just for the default?

Comment: @Salvador: just pass the name of the printer to in the _Device_ parameter to the ShInvokePrinterCommand.  I just made a test and it works like a charm.

Comment: Salvador, please read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762211.aspx) for functions before asking questions about them. Find the section about PRINTACTION_TESTPAGE and read what it says about the *lpBuf1* parameter.

Comment: I have already given you a +1. I think it is slightly unexpected to find this function among the shell functions!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for 32 bit XP, not sure about 64 bit XP. Vista and later is OK.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`PrintTestPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method the from the [`Win32_Printer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) wmi class

check this sample

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj;

procedure  PrintTestPage(const PrinterName:string);
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
  PrintResult   : Integer;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer Where Name="%s"',[PrinterName]),'WQL',0);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
  begin
    PrintResult:=FWbemObject.PrintTestPage;
    if PrintResult=0 then
     Writeln('Success')
    else
     Writeln('An error occurred');
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      PrintTestPage('MyPrinter');
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;

 Readln;
end.
```